# Best way to provide interface for attaching multiple images to a record displayed in a Winform?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on an application that allows the user to query a database for a large number of fields, and currently I need to create an interface for the user to attach images to these records that can be retrieved later.

Currently my method for storing these images is to convert the image file to a byte array and then convert that to base 64 and store it as text in the database.

My question is, what would be the best way to provide an interface for attaching these images? I was thinking I could have a ListBox that displays a small text description for each image, possibly the filename... but unless I store the filename in the database, it would not be available when I retrieve that record in the future. And even if I store the filename, it will be meaningless if the file is not stored on that client's computer.

I have also considered creating a custom Winform component that would act like a [Windows image selection window](https://yoavniran.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/desktop-background-selection-window.png), where the image would be displayed as a thumbnail PictureBox.

Are there any other ways of providing this interface that someone could suggest that I might not have thought of? And are there any pre-made components like the gallery-type component I described above? Or is this something I would have to make a custom component for?

Comment: You might want to look at the `varbinary` column type instead of using Base64 - it will be more space-efficient.

Comment: So would I just write the byte array itself to a field of that type and then back again? Or is there a conversion process I would have to use to convert it from image data to varbinary data?

Comment: Maybe this question is more fitted for [UX Stack Exchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Well it's less about UX and more about finding out what components might already be available to me to solve my problem? Mostly I was hoping there was a pre-existing gallery type widget I could use to display the images that have been attached.